# GoCV start & stop webcam recording with 2 differents API calls

Tags: api, opencv, go, webcam, go-echo

I am trying to design a small backend service in Go with the Echo library to record video from a webcam using GoCV.

I would like to make a call to start the recording and one to stop it, whereas from the example provided in the GoCV documentation you have to define the duration of the video a priori already in the call to start recording.

So I tried to make the one in the start call an infinite loop, but the call obviously remains pending until I stop the webcam with the end call and it doesn't seem to me to be a fair practice in addition to creating problems with browser timeout.

There is a poor documentation and I cannot find examples on this problem.
How can this be done with two separate calls and not knowing the length of the recording beforehand?? Thank you

[GoCV example](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/blob/release/cmd/savevideo/main.go):

```
// What it does:
//
// This example uses the VideoCapture class to capture AVI video from a connected webcam,
// then saves 100 frames to a video file on disk.
//
// How to run:
//
// savevideo [camera ID] [video file]
//
//      go run ./cmd/savevideo/main.go 0 testvideo.avi
//

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 3 {
        fmt.Println("How to run:\n\tsavevideo [camera ID] [video file]")
        return
    }

    deviceID := os.Args[1]
    saveFile := os.Args[2]

    webcam, err := gocv.OpenVideoCapture(deviceID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening video capture device: %v\n", deviceID)
        return
    }
    defer webcam.Close()

    img := gocv.NewMat()
    defer img.Close()

    if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot read device %v\n", deviceID)
        return
    }

    writer, err := gocv.VideoWriterFile(saveFile, "MJPG", 25, img.Cols(), img.Rows(), true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening video writer device: %v\n", saveFile)
        return
    }
    defer writer.Close()

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
            fmt.Printf("Device closed: %v\n", deviceID)
            return
        }
        if img.Empty() {
            continue
        }

        writer.Write(img)
    }
}
```

My code:

```
package gocvFunctions

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func GocvStartRecord(c echo.Context) error {
    fmt.Print("GocvStartRecord started\n")

    deviceID := c.QueryParam("deviceID")
    saveFile := c.QueryParam("saveFile")

    webcam, err := gocv.OpenVideoCapture(deviceID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening video capture device: %v\n", deviceID)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error opening video capture device: "+deviceID)
    }
    defer webcam.Close()

    img := gocv.NewMat()
    defer img.Close()

    if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot read device %v\n", deviceID)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Cannot read device: "+deviceID)
    }

    writer, err := gocv.VideoWriterFile(saveFile, "mp4v", 25, img.Cols(), img.Rows(), true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening video writer device: %v\n", saveFile)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error opening video writer device: "+saveFile)
    }
    defer writer.Close()

    for /* i := 0; i < 100; i++ */ {
        if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
            fmt.Printf("Device closed: %v\n", deviceID)
            return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Device closed: "+deviceID)
        }
        if img.Empty() {
            continue
        }

        writer.Write(img)
    }

    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "GocvStartRecord success")
}

func GocvStopRecord(c echo.Context) error {
    fmt.Print("GocvStopRecord started\n")

    deviceID := c.QueryParam("deviceID")
    saveFile := c.QueryParam("saveFile")

    webcam, err := gocv.OpenVideoCapture(deviceID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening video capture device: %v\n", deviceID)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error opening video capture device: "+deviceID)
    }
    defer webcam.Close()
/*
    img := gocv.NewMat()
    defer img.Close()

    if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot read device %v\n", deviceID)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Cannot read device: "+deviceID)
    }

    writer, err := gocv.VideoWriterFile(saveFile, "mp4v", 25, img.Cols(), img.Rows(), true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening video writer device: %v\n", saveFile)
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error opening video writer device: "+saveFile)
    }
    defer writer.Close()
*/
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "GocvStopRecord success")
}
```

Comment: I should have solved it by using ```goroutines```